# asynchronous in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

i want for pass array, and use data in array get data from redis to formation a new array. Then user the new array to work.

i try user async.map, following code:

```
var sampleData = [{
    'name': 'name1',
    'age': 'age1'
}, {
    'name': 'name2',
    'age': 'age2'
}, {
    'name': 'name3',
    'age': 'age3'
}];

async.mapSeries(sampleData, function (data, callback) {
    return callback(null, data['name']);
}, function (err, results) {
    console.log('results : ' + results); //results : name1,name2,name3  
});
```

but the code have not callback when the loop finish

Comment: In your `function(data, callback)` mapper function you should make the *asynchronous* call to redis???

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly the question is.
Running this code on http://requirebin.com/?gist=11136258 I got the expected result.
If you wonder why you got `name1,name2,name3` that's because you concatenate the string and the array, so the array gets coerced into a string, resulting in a comma separated list of the items.

If you want to have a mapping from a certain field in the objects to the rest of the object, you can do a `reduce` to create an object with that mapping.
You can put the entire object in there or filter out the name if you want to.
I put that example in the same gist.

Code example:

```
var async = require('async');
var sampleData = [{'name':'name1', 'age':'age1'},{'name':'name2', 'age':'age2'},{'name':'name3', 'age':'age3'}];
async.mapSeries(sampleData, function (data,callback) {
    return callback(null, data['name']);
}, function(err, results) {
    console.log('results : ', results);
});

// Getting data by name
async.reduce(sampleData, {}, function (byName, data, callback) {
  byName[data.name] = {age: data.age};
  callback(null, byName);
}, function (err, dataByName) {
    console.log('Data by name', dataByName);
});
```

Comment: i will use name1 name2 name3 to get data formation {['name1']=>{'add': 'aaa', 'age': 'age1'}
['name2']=>{'add': 'bbb', 'age': 'age1'}}.

Comment: i want user name1, name2, name3 to get data formation to two dimensional array

> { [name1]=>{'a','b'} [name2]=>{'c', 'd'} }

then use it to work.

Comment: I updated the example to show how you can do that using reduce.